# Image Path encode to Base64 -Json file

Tags: ios, json, image, base64

i am building app where I retrieve list of menus using Json file:
I got poblem within my UITableview , the loading is too slow .

example of Json:

```
"Mon": [

{
"Type" : "Breakfast",
"Name":"Sweet Potato Breakfast Taquitos",
"Price" : "OMR 1.500",
"Image":"http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4443/satbf1.jpg",
"Description": "olive oil, sweet potato  , onions, jalapenos , cilantro , salt , pepper , shredded cheddar cheese , eggs , milk, corn tortilla , olive oil "
},

{
  "Type" : "Lunch",
"Name":"Mexican Rice",
"Price" : "OMR 1.500",
"Image":"http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4296/mlunch1.jpg",
"Description": "rice, chicken broth, butter, olive oil, onion, garlic, tomato paste, lime juice, cilantro, cumin, salt"
}
]
```

I found that I have to convert my image path into Base46 string ...**(How can I do that automatically  )?and how will be the formate of my new path ??**

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1 - If you need to convert only the path into base64 you can use the php function `base64_encode()`

```
$img_path = 'http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4443/satbf1.jpg';
$b64_img_path = base64_encode($img_path);
```

2 - If you need to convert the image data into base64 all you have to do is:

```
$img_path = 'http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4443/satbf1.jpg';
$img_data = file_get_contents($img_path);
$b64_img = base64_encode($img_data);
```

3 - Use `base64_decode()` to decode you base64 string.

```
$b64_str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
$str = base64_decode($b64_str);
```